# Meteor: what does "there can be only one platform" mean?

Tags: meteor, angular, console, angular2-meteor

I'm working through the Angular2-Meteor tutorial [here](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially).  When I update the code for the app, I frequently encounter an error message, displayed in the browser console when I browse to the app running on localhost:

> Error: There can be only one platform. Destroy the previous one to create a new one.

Sometimes the app seems to be running fine.  Other times it is indeed not working.  What does this error mean, and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me when i was using the Atom editor. Atom compiles your typescript and outputs it in the same folder by default. Then Meteor sees both a *.ts and a *.js file and happily loads both of them. As a result 2 Angular platforms are created.

I don't know if you can change the *.js output folder with atom-typescript. I switched to VSCode for typescript development.

Comment: Makes sense.  I was using Atom and compiling from .ts to .js.